# Changing device web management port on Billion 7800NXL

Tags: installation, router

Does anyone know how (or even if it's possible) to change the port on a Billion BiPac 7800NXL?

I can't find anything about it in the documentation or web management.

I want to be able to forward port 80 through to a machine on my network, but it doesn't seem to allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can forward port 80 without having to change the management port, any external requests to the port are forwarded through and internal requests are redirected through to the web management.

A dyndns on the external IP always seems to redirect through to the correct machine, even from the internal network.